# trim() any leading or tailing characters that isn't Letter or Numbers

Tags: php

How can i `trim()` the following sentence

`,, This is New, A new Sentence.,`

to become

`This is New, A new Sentence`

I've tried `trim()` and `rtrim()` together and didn't work either,

```
$str = ",, This is New, A new Sentence., ";
$str = trim(rtrim($str));
```

result was always the same with or together `trim` and `rtrim()` `,, This is New, A new Sentence.,`

Is it possible to handle this using `trim()` function?

In case the solution is using `preg_replace()`, Then the current `RegEx` i use is  `preg_replace('/[\s,]+/',',',trim(rtrim($str)))`

Comment: `trim()` is used to remove whitespaces, not any other char. A solution wuold be to use regex

Comment: used $str = rtrim(trim(ltrim($str,',,')),'.,');

Comment: @Phate01 That is incorrect.  `trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string` http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: should a 'complete' sentence not include the ending period? :)

Comment: @Odyssey1111 The beginning and end can't have any special characters, Only letters and numbers, a `/` would be accepted at the end too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$str = ",, This is New, A new Sentence., ";
$str = trim(preg_replace("/^[^A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+$/", '', $str));

var_dump($str);
```

And to use `/[\s,]+/` too, try the following:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace_callback_array([
    "/^[^A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+$/" => function($match){}, 
    "/[\s,]+/" => function ($match)
    {
        return ",";
    }
    ], $str));
```

the regex will remove all trailing and leading chars from the string, that are not alphanumeric. And `trim()` will remove the whitespace

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of business logic, i.e. the aim. In your case it seems to be:

**The start and end of the string should be a letter (or presumably number).**

In which case, via REGEX, strip off anything violating this.

```
preg_replace('/^[^a-z0-9]+|[^a-z0-9]+$|[\s,]{2,}/i', '', $str);
```

Comment: Don't you want to include uppercase A-Z too?

Comment: Yes, but the example provided by the OP _,, This is New, A new Sentence.,_ does start with an uppercase

Comment: Good spot - I was confusing different questions. Edited.

Comment: what about the comma in between? Which need to persist ryt?

Comment: If possible, How can i implement your RegEx with my `/[\s,]+/` ?

Comment: This doesn't remove the inbetween comma - try it.

Comment: @Utkanos the problem is that `/[\s,]+/` keeps only one comma in between, yours works perfectly but if `a ,, b` exists, it keeps two comma, while `/[\s,]+/` keeps only 1.

Comment: Edited.........